# Географические названия, не имеющие аналога в русском языке

Tags: топонимика

Возник такой вопрос.
В книге описываются географические названия и объекты Калининграда. На русском и немецком - город Советск (нем. Tilsit). Но у некоторых названий нет русского эквивалента (напр., ручей Hufenfreigraben). Верно ли употребление этого слова латиницей, без русской транскрибации?

Возможно, не совсем подходящий для этого форума вопрос.Тем не менее буду благодарна за ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA_(%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4)):
Через парк протекает Парковый ручей (бывший Хуфенфрайграбен нем. *Hufenfreigraben*).

Из статьи о [Парковом ручье](https://lib39.ru/kray/toponymy/index.php?SECTION_ID=114&ELEMENT_ID=888):

> Бывшее немецкое название: **Hufenfreigraben**
> Русская транслитерация: **Хуфенфрайграбен**
> <...>
> Немецкое название *Hufenfreigraben* ( с нем. «Хуфенские открытые канавы») имеет историческое происхождение: оно указывает на то, что ручей протекает через кёнигсбергский пригород *Хуфен* и выбрал свое русло свободно от вмешательства человека, то есть естественным стоком воды. Современное название ручья указывает лишь на то, что он протекает через парк.

Из статьи на "Грамоте" ([Как склонять географические названия?](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/73-rubric-90)):

> Иноязычные названия, оканчивающиеся на согласный, обычно не склоняются в функции приложения: *в городе Луисвилл, в городе Мобеж, в г. Ниамет, в провинции Зядинь, близ города Мэнстон.* (Исключение составляют названия, давно заимствованные и освоенные русским языком: *в городе Вашингтоне.*)
> Если же подобные названия не употреблены в функции приложения, они, как правило, склоняются: *в городе Мантасас,* но *в 70 километрах от Мантасаса, близ города Мэнстон,* но *близ Мэнстона.*

Я бы написала так: *в ручье Хуфенфрайграбен,* но *в Хуфенфрайграбене*.

Comment: Римма, спасибо большое за ответ!

Comment: Пожалуйста-пожалуйста! Удивительное, правда, дело: "спасибо" Вы раздаете (это классно!), а ответы почему-то не оцениваете. Шикарный перевод — это действительно ценно, но вопрос-то Ваш не о переводе, а о правописании.

Comment: Я, наверное, запуталась в обозначениях. Ленюсь мануал изучить, простите.  Ответ приняла сразу, вот теперь ещё и оценила )

Comment: ​«Вот теперь тебя люблю я, вот теперь тебя хвалю я!» Здорово, что разобрались. У Вас интересные вопросы. Голосуйте чаще.

Comment: Спасибо! Буду голосовать! ))

Answer (score 2):

я не знаю немецкий и могу только использовать контекстный переводчик: ручей Hufen+frei+graben(немецкие слова легко распадаются на корни) - копыта свобода(чистый) рыть(канава).

**"Канава Чистых Копыт"/"Очищающая Копыта Канава?"**))) Хорошее название для ручья, почему нет. В этом названии прямо чувствуется благородный слог.

И тут у меня возникла мысль. Хорошо сделать так: написать название на немецком, а рядом или в скобках, его перевод на русском. Тогда, думаю, никто не расстроится. Тем более там такие звучные топонимы.

Да и вообще, я бы большинство топонимов перевел, где это возможно.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Кстати, перевод у вас вышел шикарный. Подняли мне настроение - это очень ценно ))

Answer (score 1):

Буратино, кстати перевод у вас вышел совершенно не корректным во всех отношениях. не всё можно перевести.

во-вторых, hufen - это не существительное во множественном числе, а глагол-восклицание, навроде "но", "тпру" или, даже, "табань", поскольку это команда животным в упряжи сдать назад.

и, во-первых, и это главное - Hufen не переводится в данном случае. поскольку образовано от старой немецкой сельскохозяйственной единицы измерения площади - hufe, или точнее диалектной вариации - hube, поскольку первоначально село называлось Huben.

относительно же Хуфенфрайграбена - данный полу-искусственный ручей протекал через Хуфен.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/44159)